# Is there a way to get one World File from QGIS Atlas?

Tags: atlas, qgis-2.14, world-file

I used Atlas in QGIS 2.14 to generate an image (map) and an associate world file for each lakes (> 5000) in my database.

I want to be able to see all the data in MS Excel as following:

- 1st column : Name of the lake (in my case, the file name)
- 2nd column : 1st line in the world file
- 3rd column : 2nd line in the world file
- 4th column : 3rd line in the world file
- 5th column : 4th line in the world file
- 6th column : 5th line in the world file
- 7th column : 6th line in the world file

With each line being one lake.

**Is there a way in QGIS (or any other GIS) to get one "super" world file for all my lakes instead of one per lake?**

If not, is there any other way to merge all the files to get the same result?

**EDIT : In case I'm not asking the right question, what I ultimately want is an MS Excel file with the lakes' name in one column and the corner coordinates of the map (jpg image) in separate columns.**

Comment: You can using Vector ‣ Research Tools ‣ Vector grid. then export to shapefile you will get the coordinates in the .dbf edit in excel to your topleft coordinates https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, it'd be solved by merging all shapefiles into one. It's as simple as vector -> data management tools -> merge shapefiles and then select the directory your shapefiles are into and where do you want your merged shapefile saved to.

I see, you'd either select all in the attribute table and paste it in excel, or install the xytools plugin and save attribute table to excel
[image]

Comment: All my lakes are already in a single Shapefile. I'm using Atlas to get a separate map (jpg image) for each lake. Atlas also generates a World file for each map. What I need is one MS Excel file with all the World files data inside.

Comment: Ok, found my answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986568/how-to-import-text-files-in-ms-excel-with-each-line-in-a-separate-column/).